# Send route to view Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

My Controller returns a JSON from my dbtest function that is a select in my database. I want to display that JSON in a table. I already have a function that does that.
My Controller (Controller.php):

```
public function returnJSON()
{
    $test = new user();
    return response()->json(($teste->dbtest()));
}
```

My view (welcome). Im using a JSON only for testing, and it works fine. I literally just need to get the JSON from my controller and use it in "`$json`" variable. I can use a route or anything, I just need to do it. It can't be that hard…;

```
<body onload ="CreateTableFromJSON()" style=" overflow-x:hidden !important;">
<h1>Olá,<?php echo $name; ?></h1>

@php  
    $json = '[{"COD_RAMAL":"801","COD_USU_RAMAL":"4278","RAMAL":"(31)3379-1050","DESCRICAORAMAL":null,"RAMALCORPORATIVO":"(31)3379-1050","EMAILDOUSUARIO":null},{"COD_RAMAL":"802","COD_USU_RAMAL":"4353","RAMAL":"(33)3333-3333","DESCRICAORAMAL":null,"RAMALCORPORATIVO":"(31)97159-2285","EMAILDOUSUARIO":null},{"COD_RAMAL":"803","COD_USU_RAMAL":"4254","RAMAL":" ","DESCRICAORAMAL":null,"RAMALCORPORATIVO":"","EMAILDOUSUARIO":null},{"COD_RAMAL":"804","COD_USU_RAMAL":"4051","RAMAL":"(31)3369-7032","DESCRICAORAMAL":null,"RAMALCORPORATIVO":"","EMAILDOUSUARIO":null},{"COD_RAMAL":"805","COD_USU_RAMAL":"3923","RAMAL":"(31)3369-7008","DESCRICAORAMAL":null,"RAMALCORPORATIVO":"","EMAILDOUSUARIO":null}]';
    $json_decoded = json_decode($json);
    echo '<table>';
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th>cod_ramal</th>';
        echo '<th>codousuramal</th>';
        echo '<th>ramal</th>';
        echo '<th>Descricao</th>';
        echo '<th>ramal corporativo</th>';
        echo '<th>email</th>';
      echo '</tr>';

    foreach($json_decoded as $result){
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->COD_RAMAL.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->COD_USU_RAMAL.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->RAMAL.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->DESCRICAORAMAL.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->RAMALCORPORATIVO.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$result->EMAILDOUSUARIO.'</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    @endphp
</body>       
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome',['name' =>"test"]);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you want to load it using AJAX?

Comment: Well,tbh i would like to just get the JSON i have in my route (and it is working,if i go to the route path it returns me the JSON exactly how i want) and just use this route in my "$json" in my view. Or something like that. But i just cant make it work.

Comment: What do you mean by "get the JSON"? Why do you need a route for that?

Comment: The JSON is a database select i have in my model,im returning it in my controller and i have a route accessing that controller method. I need to acess this result in my view,and i just can't seem to make that work.

Comment: Why not add that to the same controller that already renders the page? Otherwise, why not use AJAX to load it independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you can return view from controller.So you can keep your view file clean using blade template

```
public function returnJSON()
{
   $test = new user();
   return view('welcome',['userDetail'=>$teste->dbtest()]);
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>cod_ramal</th>
        <th>codousuramal</th>
        <th>ramal</th>
        <th>Descricao</th>
        <th>ramal corporativo</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($userDetail as $result)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$result->COD_RAMAL}}</td>
        <td>{{$result->COD_USU_RAMAL}}</td>
        <td>{{$result->RAMAL}}</td>
        <td>{{$result->DESCRICAORAMAL}}</td>
        <td>{{$result->RAMALCORPORATIVO}}</td>
        <td>{{$result->EMAILDOUSUARIO}}</td>
    </tr>

@endforeach
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: This actually works. If i acess the route im getting the right value.
The only problem is, i wanted to access it trough my view. Is this a bad pratice?
Because i have made this way,so now,if i access the route, the table is just returnig default with no css or js

Comment: This is almost 100% what i need. The ONLY problem is that now my default route "/'' stops working because it can't find "$userDetail" anymore. If i could just use it in the default route too it would be 100% perfect

Comment: Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\YourController::class, 'returnJSON']);

Answer (score 1):

Try this
**Your Route**

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\Controller::class, 'returnJSON']);
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function returnJSON()
{
    #code
    $jsonResponse = $yourResponse;
    $users = json_decode($jsonResponse);
    return view('welcome', compact($users));
}
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user['detail1'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user['detail2'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ok,i'll try it,thanks for the help.
But to try it should i delete my Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome',['name' =>"test"]);
});
 route?

Comment: @Dan I think you need to delete it, because your route now leads to another function.

Comment: @Dan It would also be nicer if you used a separate controller for each page or topic you cover. For example for users 'UsersController.php'